# In R: Create a data frame which includes consecutive observations only and a variable indicating sequence number

Tags: r, date, sequence

I have a data frame with column names similar to below, in which each row is one observation:
user_id; date; Var_1; Var_2

Each user_id can have 0 or 1 observations for each date. Only dates with an observation are included in the data frame for each user.

From this data, I want to create a data frame containing these variables (and the ones described below) but it should only contain observations for 3 successive dates (for each user). Days in each succession should be numbered 1 to 3 and each succession should be numbered as well.

For instance if user with user_id == 1 has observations on the following date: 2020-01-01, 2020-01-03, 2020-01-04, 2020-01-05, 2020-01-06, 2020-01-10, 2020-01-12, 2020-01-13, 2020-01-14.
And user with user_id == 2 has observations on the following dates: 2020-01-01, 2020-01-03, 2020-01-04, 2020-01-06, 2020-01-10, 2020-01-12, 2020-01-15, 2020-01-16, 2020-01-17

Then the new data frame should include:

user_id      date      Sequence      Day      Var_1      Var_2      
1            20-01-03      1                  1            *value*            *value*      
1            20-01-04      1                  2            *value*            *value*      
1            20-01-05      1                  3            *value*            *value*      
1            20-01-04      2                  1            *value*            *value*      
1            20-01-05      2                  2            *value*            *value*      
1            20-01-06      2                  3            *value*            *value*      
1            20-01-12      3                  1            *value*            *value*      
1            20-01-13      3                  2            *value*            *value*      
1            20-01-14      3                  3            *value*            *value*      
2            20-01-15      1                  1            *value*            *value*      
2            20-01-16      1                  2            *value*            *value*      
2            20-01-17      1                  3            *value*            *value*

(where *value* is the value of the observation for the variable)

Thank you for your help with this tricky problem !

Best wishes,
Eric

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you can try working with. I'm sure there are better ways than this, but it seems to work.

Filter by identifying rows that are the beginning of 3-day sequences. To do that, calculate difference `diff` between dates, and identify dates where the subsequent two rows have a `diff` of one day.

Knowing the start dates of sequences, you can enumerate these as `sequence`. Then, use `map` to expand to 3 day sequences based on these starting dates. After that, you can enumerate again for `day` after grouping by both `user_id` and `sequence`.

Finally, would join result back to your original data to get your `Var_1`, `Var_2`, etc.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  select(user_id, date) %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  mutate(diff = c(0, diff(date))) %>%
  filter((lead(diff, 1L) == 1 & lead(diff, 2L) == 1)) %>%
  mutate(sequence = row_number(),
         date = map(date, seq.Date, length = 3, by = "1 day")) %>%
  unnest(cols = date) %>%
  group_by(user_id, sequence) %>%
  mutate(day = row_number()) %>%
  inner_join(df, by = c("user_id", "date")) %>%
  select(-diff)
```

**Output**

```
   user_id date       sequence   day Var_1 Var_2
     <dbl> <date>        <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1       1 2020-01-03        1     1     2    17
 2       1 2020-01-04        1     2     3    16
 3       1 2020-01-05        1     3     4    15
 4       1 2020-01-04        2     1     3    16
 5       1 2020-01-05        2     2     4    15
 6       1 2020-01-06        2     3     5    14
 7       1 2020-01-12        3     1     7    12
 8       1 2020-01-13        3     2     8    11
 9       1 2020-01-14        3     3     9    10
10       2 2020-01-15        1     1    16     3
11       2 2020-01-16        1     2    17     2
12       2 2020-01-17        1     3    18     1
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(user_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), date = structure(c(18262, 18264, 18265, 18266, 
18267, 18271, 18273, 18274, 18275, 18262, 18264, 18265, 18267, 
18271, 18273, 18276, 18277, 18278), class = "Date"), Var_1 = 1:18, 
    Var_2 = 18:1), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L
))
```

Comment: Hi Ben
Thank you very much for your contribution which helps a lot!

Best wishes,
Eric